# Stored Procedures last access time?

Tags: sql-server-2008, introspection

Is it possible to find out when a Stored Procedure was last accessed?

I tried the following:

```
SELECT * 
FROM sys.dm_db_index_usage_stats 
WHERE [database_id] = DB_ID()  
    AND [object_id] = OBJECT_ID('stored procedure name')
```

and it returns a blank resultset.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe this is possible should the sproc still be in the procedure cache on the server at which point you can query sys.dm_exec_query_stats.

After that you are down to logging and tracing I'm afraid.

Comment: Thanks for the information.  It is a shame that you can't actually view when a SP was last executed. :o(

Answer (score 2):

Add a log entry as the first line of the stored procedures:

```
insert into dbo.ProcLog (procname, date) values ('MyProc',getdate())
```

Comment: @Andomar, I'd use `OBJECT_NAME(@@PROCID)` instead of 'MyProc', much easier to maintain.

Answer (score 1):

here is a generic line of code you can place in every procedure, it will include the proper procedure name, without hard coding it.

```
INSERT INTO YourLog 
        (RunDate,ProcedureName,...) 
    VALUES 
        (GETDATE(),OBJECT_NAME(@@PROCID),...)
```